# Creating triangles from points with given bearing and leg length using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon-creation, create

I have a spreadsheet that contains ID, LAT_DD, LONG_DD, Bearing and LEN fields. I need to automate a way to create a triangle for every point identified in the table and I have no idea how. I know the steps should be as follows:

1. Create points from X,Y (Creating the known vertex, beginning, of my triangle)
2. Create triangles

   - Use bearing for triangle bisector
   - Use LEN for length of legs radiating from known vertex.

I'm fairly new to GIS programming and don't even know where to start. I can create the points, but that's it.

Comment: If you've been able to create the points using ArcPy then presenting that code would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS has a number of geodetic operators available in the Projection Engine exposed through ArcPy as methods on the [PointGeometry](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/pointgeometry.htm) type.

The so-called "Forward Problem of Geodesy" is solved by the `PointGeometry.pointFromAngleAndDistance()` request, with required parameters `angle` (in degrees) and `distance` (in meters), and optional parameter `method` (one of `GEODESIC`, `GREAT_ELLIPTIC`, `LOXODROME`, and `PRESERVE_SHAPE` -- `PLANAR` is not available for geographic coordinate systems).

The "Inverse" (aka "Reverse") problem is solved by `PointGeometry.angleAndDistanceTo()` with required parameter `other` (the target `PointGeometry`), and optional parameter `method` (same as above), and returns a *tuple* of angle (in degrees) and distance (in meters) from the reference point.

Note that ArcPy also has a `Point` object, but this is a different object, which just stores multidimensional vertices.  A `Point` is used with a `SpatialReference` to construct a `PointGeometry`.

The full solution for computing distance from New York (JFK) to Tokyo (Narita) in WGS84, and calculating the halfway point between them would look like:

```py
import arcpy
gcs = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
gcs.setFalseOriginAndUnits(-400.0,-400.0,10000000)

jfk  = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(-73.7781,40.6413),gcs)
nrt  = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(140.3929,35.7720),gcs)

bearing,distance = jfk.angleAndDistanceTo(nrt,'GEODESIC')
print(" Bearing = {:.2f} deg".format(bearing))
print("Distance = {:.2f} meters".format(distance))

midpoint = jfk.pointFromAngleAndDistance(bearing,distance*0.5,'GEODESIC')
print("Midpoint = {:4f},{:.4f}".format(
        midpoint.firstPoint.X,
        midpoint.firstPoint.Y))
```

Which results in:

```
 Bearing = -27.32 deg
Distance = 10853320.27 meters
Midpoint = -152.890242,69.4824
```

and *feels* right (10853 kilometer NNW polar route over Alaska).

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS may have its own operation to calculate a point on a specific bearing and distance, but a great source for these types of calculations is the Aviation Formulary at:  https://edwilliams.org/avform.htm

In particular you want the "Lat/Long given radial and distance" :

> Lat/lon given radial and distance
>
> A point {lat,lon} is a distance d out on the tc radial from point 1 if:
>
> ```
> lat=asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d)+cos(lat1)*sin(d)*cos(tc))
> IF (cos(lat)=0)
>    lon=lon1      // endpoint a pole
> ELSE
>    lon=mod(lon1-asin(sin(tc)*sin(d)/cos(lat))+pi,2*pi)-pi
> ENDIF
> ```
>
> This algorithm is limited to distances such that dlon around less than one quarter of the circumference of the earth in longitude. A >completely general, but more complicated algorithm is necessary if greater distances >are allowed:
>
> ```
> lat =asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d)+cos(lat1)*sin(d)*cos(tc))
> dlon=atan2(sin(tc)*sin(d)*cos(lat1),cos(d)-sin(lat1)*sin(lat))
> lon=mod( lon1-dlon +pi,2*pi )-pi
> ```

Note that trigonometry functions are in radians - you'll have to convert to/from degrees (Radians = Degrees*PI/180 )